# Field update From Process builder

Tags: process-builder

In formula Evaluate True
if profile is **Int. Op. Procurement**  or **Int. Op. Accounting** and Status(picklist) is "Solved"then process builder fire update the status solved to "New"

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: $USer.UserName = 'Int. Op. Procurement" OR $USer.UserName = 'Int. Op. Accounting" and Status = 'Solved'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Add criteria:
[image]

Define action. Choose object type you need to update and picklist value.
[image]